# Is this some kind of warming oven?

Tags: oven

These are two chef's kitchens. In both images, there is a small oven(?) on the stainless steel shelf above the main oven. In each image, it appears to be the same device. Any idea what that is and who makes them?

Looks to be some sort of warming oven?

[image: home kitchen 2]

[image: home kitchen 1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a salamander. Its just a small broiler like the one in your oven.

Comment: Well, generally higher-powered than the ones in home ovens, but that's the idea.

Comment: I guess if you are pro chef making specialty dishes at home, that is useful but probably overly excessive for the cook enthusiast? Seems like the oven broiler would do about anything you need?

Comment: Like @FuzzyChef said they can reach higher temperatures then the average oven broiler. I believe its something like ~800 vs ~500 degrees which some may prefer for cooking things like steaks.

Comment: Well, if you make a LOT of creme brulee, I could see wanting one, I guess.  But yeah, I'd regard it as overkill for any home cook.  Among other things, salamanders have no door and are on all the time, so they use a LOT of gas/power.